# IrpDeleteFileForce to symbolic link file

Tags: c, windows, winapi, driver, kernel-mode

Based in [this reference](https://blog.csdn.net/zy_strive_2012/article/details/78337637), i'm testing `IrpDeleteFileForce()` with symbolic link files but status is always **0xC000000D** (STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER) to **`pFileObject`**. I only added `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` to *CreateOptions* parameter (of [`IoCreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreatefile) function) in `GetDriveObject()` routine and `IrpCreateFile()` routine returns STATUS_SUCCESS, i not understood why `IrpDeleteFileForce()` failed  :-(

Some solution to this?

```
NTSTATUS GetDriveObject(PUNICODE_STRING pDriveName, PDEVICE_OBJECT* DeviceObject, PDEVICE_OBJECT* ReadDevice)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    HANDLE DeviceHandle = NULL;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatus;
    PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject;

    if (pDriveName == NULL || DeviceObject == NULL || ReadDevice == NULL)
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objectAttributes, pDriveName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);

    status = IoCreateFile(&DeviceHandle, SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_ANY_ACCESS, &objectAttributes, &ioStatus, NULL, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_OPEN, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, NULL, IO_NO_PARAMETER_CHECKING);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return status;

    status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(DeviceHandle, FILE_READ_DATA, *IoFileObjectType, KernelMode, &pFileObject, NULL);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        ZwClose(DeviceHandle);
        return status;
    }

    if (pFileObject->Vpb == 0 || pFileObject->Vpb->RealDevice == NULL)
    {
        ObDereferenceObject(pFileObject);
        ZwClose(DeviceHandle);
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }

    *DeviceObject = pFileObject->Vpb->DeviceObject;
    *ReadDevice = pFileObject->Vpb->RealDevice;

    ObDereferenceObject(pFileObject);
    ZwClose(DeviceHandle);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

***GetDriveObject()***

```
status = IoCreateFile(&DeviceHandle, SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_ANY_ACCESS, &objectAttributes, &ioStatus, NULL, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_OPEN, FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, NULL, IO_NO_PARAMETER_CHECKING);
```

***IrpCreateFile()***

```
IrpSp->Parameters.Create.Options = (FILE_OPEN_IF << 24) | FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT | 0;
```